# Big endian byte array to small endian struct elements in C, arm

Tags: c, struct, arm, stm32, endianness

In my application microcontroller stm32f103 is receiving by USART fixed lenght messages, they contains gps velocity which is big endian data. But elements in structure are small endian. Is there any way without doing it manually to write it in correct way?

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t test1;
    uint16_t test2;
}Mst;

uint8_t myArray[6] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06 };

void main()
{
    Mst * myStruct_p = (Mst)myArray;
}
```

But after that `myStruct_p->test1` equals `0x030201`, but should be `0x010203`, and `myStruct_p->test2` equals `0x0605`, but should be `0x0506`.

Comment: you have to swizzle the bytes anyway, and there is possible alignment issues, so why not use reliable, portable, code that always works?   shift and or.  isnt going to make the machine code any better trying to use ghee whiz language magic.

Comment: i forgot, struct is defined with packed attribute typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)), in this moment it works as i wrote above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is ARM-Cortex M3 we can use special processor instructions. ARM CMSIS have a very handy intrinsic functions `__REV` & `__REV16` which actually compile to the single machine code instruction.

```
typedef union 
{
    struct 
    {
        uint32_t test1;
        uint16_t test2;
    };
    uint8_t bytes[6];
}Mst;

Mst mst = {.bytes = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06 }};

void main()
{
    mst.test1 = __REV(mst.test1);
    mst.test2 = __REV16(mst.test2);
}
```

Comment: any comment silent DV-ter?

Comment: sory for silecne i had small problems with swd programmer:D, your answer looks like best option, im going to try it tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Casting in that way won't work.

You can do a "deserialize" operation.

Although this might be slower than some other methods, it allows you to control the protocol better (e.g. the `struct` member order doesn't have to follow the protocol) And, there might be padding in the struct, which would show up if we added (e.g.) `uint32_t test3;` to the end of the struct.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    uint32_t test1;
    uint16_t test2;
} Mst;

uint8_t myArray[6] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06 };

uint32_t
get32(uint8_t **base)
{
    uint8_t *ptr;
    uint32_t val = 0;

    ptr = *base;

    for (int len = sizeof(uint32_t);  len > 0;  --len) {
        val <<= 8;
        val |= *ptr++;
    }

    *base = ptr;

    return val;
}

uint16_t
get16(uint8_t **base)
{
    uint8_t *ptr;
    uint16_t val = 0;

    ptr = *base;

    for (int len = sizeof(uint16_t);  len > 0;  --len) {
        val <<= 8;
        val |= *ptr++;
    }

    *base = ptr;

    return val;
}

int
main(void)
{
    Mst myS;

    uint8_t *arr = myArray;

    myS.test1 = get32(&arr);
    myS.test2 = get16(&arr);

    printf("test1=%8.8X test2=%4.4X\n",myS.test1,myS.test2);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Yes guys that will work but, i would like to use the processor as little as possible. This is rather manualy putting bytes in to correct order. Also Procedure `Mst * struct_p = (Mst*)myArray` works safe, because while defining `struct` i use `__attribute__((packed))`, just forgoten to write this

I was going to mention/suggest `packed` as a possibility.

In either case you can use [under GNU]: `byteswap.h` to get `bswap_*`. Endian swapping is quite common, so these are [highly] optimized for the given arch. They can even invoke compiler intrinsics (e.g. `__builtin_bswap32`) which utilize any special instructions the arch has (e.g. `x86` has the `bswap` instruction, and `arm` has `rev16`).

So, you can do [i.e. replace the `for` loop with] (e.g.) `bswap_*`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <byteswap.h>

typedef struct {
    uint32_t test1;
    uint16_t test2;
    uint32_t test3;
} __attribute__((__packed__)) Mst;

uint8_t myArray[] = {
    0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04,
    0x05, 0x06,
    0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A
};

void
getall(Mst *myS)
{

    myS->test1 = bswap_32(myS->test1);
    myS->test2 = bswap_16(myS->test2);
    myS->test3 = bswap_32(myS->test3);
}

int
main(void)
{
    Mst *myS = (Mst *) myArray;

    getall(myS);

    printf("test1=%8.8X test2=%4.4X test3=%8.8X\n",
        myS->test1,myS->test2,myS->test3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are wrong. Pointer punning will work in this case. The question was not about the punning but about the endianness change

Comment: do not define standard types. Just include `stdint.h`

Comment: @P__J__ I'm not "wrong" because I did _not_ say you _had_ to, merely that you "can" do it this way.

Comment: *`Casting in that way won't work.`*. 1. Punning will work in this case. 2. There is no "casting" here.

Comment: @P__J__ Huh? Isn't `Mst * myStruct_p = (Mst)myArray;` a cast? And, punning isn't a good thing to do in the general case because of the alignment issue I mentioned (re. `test3`).

Comment: First of all it will not compile. it has to be Mst * myStruct_p = (Mst *)myArray;` It is called pointer punning and the cast only suppresses the compiler warning.

Comment: @P__J__ "First of all it will not compile". Yes, hence "Casting in that way won't work.". P.S. I'm _not_ your DV'er. The criterion for DV on an answer is "egregiously" wrong. But maybe you got DV'ed for nitpicking [and DVing?] my answer here.

Comment: Yes guys that will work but, i would like to use the processor as little as possible. This is rather manualy putting bytes in to correct order. Also Procedure Mst * struct_p = (Mst*)myArray works safe, because while defining struct i use __attribute__((packed)), just forgoten to write this

Comment: Yep also works fine, but i found that __REV() fucncion which is represended by single assembler line have much more performance on Cortex M3 processor, thanks for answer it will be helpfull for someone who works on other devices or just  for someone who dont carry about performance

Comment: The `bswap_32` generates a [single line] `rev` instruction [and `bswap_16` generates `rev16`]

Answer (score 0):

Overlaying a struct pointer onto a byte array may not necessarily work due to alignment issues and structure padding.

The proper way would be to first use `memcpy` to copy over the elements:

```
Mst myStruct;
memcpy(&myStruct.test1, myArray, sizeof(myStruct.test1);
memcpy(&myStruct.test2, myArray + 4, sizeof(myStruct.test2);
```

Then use `ntohs` and `ntohl` which converts 16 and 32 bit values respectively from big endian format to the host's endianness.

```
myStruct.test1 = ntohl(myStruct.test1);
myStruct.test2 = ntohs(myStruct.test2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to convert 8bit data into big endian let say data format will be in order (A B C D) and in little endian data format will be (D C B A) if final result will be stored in 32bit variable and if 16 bit variable then format will (A B) and (B A) .

So this can be done with little bit shifting technique if you know your UART data comming in which format.

Let us first assume that your UART data comes in Little endian and you want it in big endian then you can do like this.

```
//no structure required
uint32_t myValue;
uint16_t value;
uint8_t myArray[4] = { 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01 }; 
// little endian data for 32 bit

uint8_t A[2] = {0x02 ,0x01};  // little endian data for 16 bit
void main()
{
    myValue = myArray[3]<<24 | myArray[2]<<16 | myArray[1]<<8 | myArray[0]; // result in big endian 32 bit value

   value = A[1]<<8 | A[0];  // result in big endian 16bit value
}
```